# Формы, как работать с ними?

Tags: html, form

Помогите, я совсем начинающий. Чтобы сделать систему регистрации для сайта надо ли мне использовать формы? Мне не понятен принцип работы форм.

Comment: Кстати, если вы правильно выберете метки, уже можно получить более информативный ответ, а так же воспользоваться поиском по меткам. Вашему вопросу соответствуют [html](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/html/), [form](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/form/), по второй метке, найдете много полезного, очень относящегося к вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

1. Выучить HTML, CSS
2. Выучить PHP, MySQL
3. Научиться это все связывать
4. Почитать что такое sql injection
5. Используя п. 2 предотвратить п.4

Спустя пару лет заработает система регистрации(надежная)!
Если быстро то:

1. Идем на Youtube
2. Вводим в поиске PHP Tutorial: Professional Login System и PHP Tutorial: Professional Registration System и смотрим уроки.

Answer (score 0):

Клиенту вы отправляете страницу с формой:

```
<form action="http://example.com/register.php" method="post">
  Почта: <input name="reg_email" type="text"/><br/>
  Пароль: <input name="reg_password" type="password"/>
</form>
```

а на сервере обрабатываете данные из полей формы, например так:

```
<?php RegisterUser($_POST["reg_email"], $_POST["reg_password"]); ?>
```

Comment: Паролю type="password" name="password"
Почте name="email"
Тогда в $_POST будут эти поля

Comment: @Dem спасибо, я совсем забыл как это делается

Answer (score 0):

1. Принцип работы прост- в каждое из полей формы заносится информация, которая передается и обрабатывается.
2. А что касается того, нужно ли вам самому лично делать форму регистрации- зависит от того, какой у вас сайт. Например, для того, чтобы добавить форму регистрации на некоторые CMS, достаточно установить соответствующий компонент.
    Можно поподробнее?